# IIS7 e ASPX Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp, iis-7

Boa noite senhores, estou com um problema em uma aplicação. Está aplicação foi desenvolvida em ASPX e estava rodando em um servidor Windows server 2005 normalmente, porém o servidor foi atualizado para Windows server 2008 e agora a aplicação exibe essa mensagem de erro:

> The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by
>   the static file handler.

As outras aplicações em ASP.NET MVC estão normais, apenas as em ASPX estão com esse problema. 
Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser?
Já tentei várias configurações de pool's  porém sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Após alguma pesquisa verifiquei que possivelmente falta uma configuração no IIS.

```
cmd -> right click -> Run as administrator

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762287/script-not-served-by-static-file-handler-on-iis7-5